# Совет по адаптивной верстке

Tags: вёрстка, адаптивная-верстка

Хотел бы услышать советы по верстке адаптивной версии сайта:

- с чего начинать;
- на какие моменты уделить больше внимания(времени);
- какие разрешения экранов наиболее распространены;
- стоит ли придерживаться принципа "Mobile First".

Использовать Bootstrap нет желания - хочу сам разобраться в этом)

Если есть книги(желательно на русском) - буду очень признателен.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Привет!

Медиа-запросы всегда могут быть разные. Кто-то указывает min-width и max-width кто-то нет. Если на пробу - эти медиа-запросы подойдут. Самые что ни на есть стандартные:

```
@media only screen and (max-width : 1200px) {

}
@media only screen and (max-width : 992px) {

}
@media only screen and (max-width : 768px) {

}
@media only screen and (max-width : 480px) {

}
@media only screen and (max-width : 320px) {

}
```

А вообще, они указываются в зависимости от потребностей.

Для старта отлично подойдет книга "HTML5 и CSS3 Разработка сайтов для любых браузеров и устройств" автор Бен Фрейн.

Comment: не стоит явно давать ссылку на электронные книгу, если сама по себе книга не распространяется бесплатно.

Comment: понял. спасибо. укажу сейчас название и автора

Comment: Спасибо! Очень выручили.

Comment: Рад помочь! Успехов Вам!)